# Better way to filter documents on mongodb using properties from another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to filter a document on mongodb using a property from another collection, but the problem is that I need to get all objects first and then do the filter. Here is my current situation:

**Current data:**

```
/* Message collection */
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("571063533e41b42c2753828a"),
    "user" : ObjectId("570ae3d0a27d4cd44730fc38"),
    "text" : "First text",
    "enabled" : true,
    "deleted" : false,
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5712a9be27adcff81ea5a39f"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5f236vgh74de563swer120rt"),
    "text" : "Second text",
    "deleted" : false,
    "enabled" : true,
    "__v" : 0
}

/* User collection */
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570ae3d0a27d4cd44730fc38"),
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "showMessage" : true,
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f236vgh74de563swer120rt"),
    "email" : "test1@test.com",
    "showMessage" : false,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

**Current way to filter:**

```
Message.aggregate([{
            $match: {
                enabled: true,
                deleted: false
            }
        }, {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                localField: 'user',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'user'
            }
        }], function(err, messages) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                var filteredMessages = this.filterMessages(messages);
                //do other stuff with the filtered data
            }
        });

filterMessages(messages) {
    return messages.filter((current) => {
        return current.user[0].showMessage;
    });
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get the `messages` using the property `showMessages` from `user` but I'm performing the filter after I get all the messages first and this is an inefficient way to do this.

Is there a way to get only the messages I need, filtering them using a property from another collection?

**Note:** I need to get all the messages filtered with the user property no the other way around, I mean, I can't get the users and after that filter the messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it in the aggregate directly instead:

```js
Message.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "enabled": true,
    "deleted": false  
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "localField": "user",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "user"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "user" },
  { "$redact": {
      "if": "$user.showMessage",
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
  }}
],function(err,messages) {
    if (err) reject(err);
    // Already filtered
})
```

So you [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the single relation ( since [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is a "left join ) and then simply [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) on the condition where the value was `true/false`.

Or do the `$lookup` in reverse, which may be more performant:

```js
User.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "showMessage": true } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "messages",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "user",
    "as": "messages"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$messages" },
  { "$match": {
      "messages.enabled": true,
      "messages.deleted": false
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": "$messages._id",
    "user": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "email": "$email",
      "showMessage": "$showMessage"
    },
    "text": "$messages.text",
    "deleted": "$messages.deleted",
    "enabled": "$messages.enabled"
  }}
],function(err,messages) {

})
```

At present the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator itself does not "query" documents based on any other condition than the matching of "local" and "foreign" field properties. This may well change in later releases.

For now though, you do such futher "filtering" in subsequent aggregation pipeline stages.

---

The alternate case is to in fact query in "reverse" where you take the `_id` values of valid `User` data and then only retrieve messages. But only of course if the resulting list for [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) is in fact not too large:

```js
async.waterfall
  [
    function(callback) {
      User.find({ "showMesage": true }).select("_id").exec(callback);
    },
    function(users,callback) {
      Message.find({
        "user": { "$in": users.map((current) => { return current._id }) },
        "enabled": true,
        "deleted": false
      }).populate("user").exec(callback);
    }
  ],function(err,messages) {
    // filter and populated
  }
)
```

It's additional queries as compared to the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) , however it's processing less results on the end match.

It really depends on what your case is with the data as to which works best here, so you really should test it. My guess would say that the "reverse" collecion choice with [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)  or the latter case just using [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) would be the better option. But it depends really on which query produces the least results as to which "order" is best.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you suggest some reference links to expand these concepts?